# Regex To Check If Root Directory?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Basically, I want to redirect paths like this:

> /index.php
>
> /register
>
> /login.html

But not like this:

> /img/picture1.jpg
>
> /style/main.css
>
> /js/jquery.js

How can I do this with RegEx?

Comment: Which directive you're redirecting with matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule`s in `.htaccess` files aren't passed the initial slash, so all you need to do is check for the presence or absence of any other slashes.

```
Rewrite... ...[/]... ...
Rewrite... ...[^/]... ...
```

Comment: Try `^[^/]*$` - that will match a filename if it doesn't contain any slashes.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do the trick.

```
 (^/[^/]*$)
```